# What format is lat/long stored in OSM PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

**Question:**
How do I to get the lat, long for all the [toll booths](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3abarrier=toll_booth) stored in OSM for Virginia?

**Current Query:**

```
> gis=# select * from planet_osm_nodes where ('toll_booth' = ANY(tags)); 

     id     |    lat    |    lon     |                            tags                            
------------+-----------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------
  496668427 | 448545276 | -881565606 | {name,"Airport Parking",barrier,toll_booth}
  525372041 | 463020204 | -874380697 | {name,"Swift Run Gap Entrance Station",barrier,toll_booth}
  526241181 | 470778112 | -870435097 | {name,"Front Royal Entrance Station",barrier,toll_booth}
  534508045 | 458513289 | -877777774 | {name,"Rockfish Gap Entrance Station",barrier,toll_booth}
  563894077 | 470183057 | -857852817 | {barrier,toll_booth}
  ...
```

[Rest of the table](https://gist.github.com/dasickis/5297171)

**Additional Info**

1. [OSM Import Log](https://gist.github.com/dasickis/5340077)
2. [Failed Attempts](https://gist.github.com/dasickis/5340147)
3. Tutorial -- [manually building a tile server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server/)
4. Data source -- [Cloudmade/virginia.osm.bz2](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/americas/northern_america/united_states/virginia/).

Comment: Why was this question voted down? I've tried to google and search this stackexchange but haven't been able to find the answer.

Comment: I really don't know why it was downvoted. It's an interesting question.

Comment: Although I haven't downvoted this question, I find it incomprehensible. First, clearly the "Dividing by 100" values were *not* obtained by dividing any of the preceding by 100. Second, it appears at the outset that somebody has simply stored some kind of numbers (as `integer` types, evidently) and *called* them `lat` and `lon`--but what is the poor reader supposed to make of this, in the absence of any further information?

Comment: The lat/lon aren't multiplied by 10, they are in a different projection it is supposed to be EPSG:3857.

Comment: How do I convert back to lat, long? I tried this script: http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/ and using `MetersToLatLon(448545276 , -881565606) => (-90.0, 4029.3507705040915)`

Comment: I did not downvote this question either but I think it could benefit greatly from you using the edit button to revise it to "tell the story" of your problem rather than relying on potential answerers having to follow multiple links in order to try and piece it together for themselves.  Also, your last Comment looks like it should be posted as a New Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who ask for : lon, lat from planet_osm_nodes, here is your response:

```
select lon::numeric/10000000 as lon, lat::numeric/10000000 as lat from planet_osm_nodes
```

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you're querying the wrong table; look for a table called `planet_osm_point`.

In `planet_osm_point`, geometries are stored as `geometry` type; this allows the database to use spatial indexes and spatial operators, features that would be impossible with lat/longs stored as integers.

The default name of the geometry column used by `osm2pgsql` is "way" and the default projection is 900913 (also known as 3857):

```
osm=# select st_asewkt(way), name, amenity from planet_osm_point where place = 'city' limit 1;
                      st_asewkt                       |   name    | amenity 
------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------
 SRID=900913;POINT(2362914.15411575 5741085.65649082) | Timișoara |
```

The `planet_osm_nodes` table you refer is listed (see [osm2pgsql wiki entry](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema#planet_osm_nodes)) as a temporary table used when running the importer with limited memory ("slim" mode).

Comment: Nice so using your point and using the `MetersToLatLon` from the script in my question, I get: http://goo.gl/maps/xwxLd. However, how do I then query this table for tags such as toll_booth. 

The schema has a `toll` column, however: 

`gis=# select count(toll) from planet_osm_point; `
`count = 0` 

Though there's 62 toll_booths in `planet_osm_nodes`

Comment: I don't know what MetersToLatLon does. If your planet_osm_points has less points than planet_osm_nodes it's likely your osm2pgsql import went wrong. Look for errors.

Comment: Also check that your import style file actually contains an entry for attribute name "toll" (see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Import_style). If it's not there, osm2pgsql will not add it to the table definition.

Comment: Thanks! here's the output for my run: https://gist.github.com/dasickis/5340077. It doesn't seem that there's any errors except for out of memory.

Comment: Did you check your default.style file for an entry for the "toll_booth" attribute? Presuming the id field is common between planet_osm_nodes and planet_osm_point, what does "select name from planet_osm_point where osm_id = 496668427" return?

Answer (score 2):

Although you deleted it from your question, there is something wrong with your table::

```
**Schema:** 
> gis=# \d planet_osm_nodes Table "public.planet_osm_nodes" 
 Column | Type | Modifiers an 
--------+---------+-----------
     id | bigint  | not null
    lat | integer | not null
    lon | integer | not null
   tags | text[]  |
```

Why should lat and lon be integer values? I guess on importing the comma just disappeared, and centimeter values are stored as metres.

As mentioned above, the useful geometry is stored in `planet_osm_points`.

Comment: I am finding parks from planet_osm_polygon and i have few questions:
1. after importing there is no planet_osm_nodes table
2. Is there any way to convert  2362914.15411575 5741085.65649082 alt long to the one accepted by google

Answer (score 1):

OSM2PGSQL nodes table is usable, you "simply" need to divide your lat/lon by 100.

With the first record of your sample :

SELECT
ST_AsText(
ST_Transform(
ST_GeomFromText('POINT('||'-881565606'/100||' '||'448545276'/100||')',3785 ),4326))

Result : "POINT(-79.1923852433996 37.3317650468903)"

Comment: This is integer division, which truncates `'448545276'/100` to `4485452`. Use `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon / 100.0, lat / 100.0), 3785)` to properly construct the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking to do something like this with OSM data, here is a overpass query that selects all tollbooths in Virginia and gives you a CSV file with lat/lon

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/aTR

```
[out:csv(::"id", name, ::lat, ::lon)];
area
  ["admin_level"="4"]
  ["border_type"="state"]
  ["name:en"="Virginia"]
  ({{bbox}});

node
  [barrier=toll_booth]
  (area);
out body qt;

>;
out skel qt;
```

Also don't forget to read up on OpenStreetMap's license before using the data http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright